# Href on random element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, uri

I find myself using this method a ton to perform actions based on a anchor tag's URL (with jQuery):

```
("a").live("click", function(event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    // do something with URL
}
```

Elsewhere in my app, I've got some tabular data which I'm adding inline edits to. When you double click a `<td>` in the `<table>`, it makes the data editable (text, date select, etc) and hitting "enter" will make an `$.ajax` request to save the new value. My question is, if each one of these `<td>`'s has a href associated with it, how/where should I store the uri?

For example, a `<td>` would have a URL like */articles/field/title/id/5* which I would parse using javascript and send a post using some of the params.

Is this acceptable:

```
<td href="/articles/field/title/id/5">
```

And then use the same javascript as above? Or...

- Should I add a hidden  inside the
  ?
- Should I wrap the content in
  an  tag inside the  and make
  *that* double-clickable instead?
- Or should I use some other property?

Ideas very much welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an option would be something like:

```
<td id="-articles-field-title-id-5">
```

in the case of not using IDs, "-" Can be any character.

Comment: Really simple solution, but works perfectly for me! I'll start messing around with the "data" feature of HTML5 later ;)

Comment: var uri = self.attr("id").replace(/\-/g, "/") + "/value/" + val;

Comment: yes, that's the idea, replacing the ID character "-" with "/". 
As commented "@ VoteyDisciple" is not a valid structure to add the attribute "href" to the "tr". But many other plugins use to add additional attribute (not a "href") to work on that element. do not really know how this affects the HTML structure, but put it in the ID makes it valid in HTML.

Answer (score 3):

`href` is not a valid attribute of the `<td>` tag.  If you want the contents to be clickable in that manner, wrap the inside in a traditional `<a>` tag and handle that as you would any other link.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery optionally has a metadata plugin, where attributes are stored in the `class` attribute:

```
<td class="myClass { myAttrib: 'attrVal', mySecondAttrib: 69 }">
```

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata